# What is the 3rd argument type for getSupportLoaderManager(id, args, ??)

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-loadermanager

I've an AsyncTaskLoader method which restarts the current Loader,

It's for school purpose,

```
private void startAsyncTaskLoader() 
{
    getSupportLoaderManager().restartLoader(TASK_ID, null, this);
}
```

I can check the solution online on the school github but this is the good one, 
But in my android studio "this" (3rd argument) is incorrect type...

```
--> 
Wrong 3rd argument type. Found: 'com.openclassrooms.freezap.Controllers.MainActivity', required: 'android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<java.lang.Object>'
```

I understand I placed a context argument (MainActivity) but I don't have an instance of LoaderManager.

Comment: Its a callback `LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>` . You need to Implement it to provide this or you can use it as Anonymous  class.

Comment: @Adm How can i use it as anonymous class ?

Comment: Actually do not use anonymous class . Just Use `class MainActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>`.. And use `Alt+Enter` on error to implement overrided methods..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the 3rd argument type for getSupportLoaderManager(id, args, ??)

That method takes no arguments.

If you really mean `restartLoader()`, the third parameter is `android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks`, as you can tell from your error message and from [the documentation for `restartLoader()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/LoaderManager#restartloader).